# "Network request failed" when calling localhost IIS from React native app

Tags: android, react-native, iis, localhost, certificate

I am developing React Native application for Android (later the same goes on IOS) and also certain REST APIs. I have the backend and APIs running on localhost which is accessible by using the machine's IP in LAN (device and server are in the same LAN). The same APIs are working when calling them from Postman or another mobile app. Also if I call the same API on our production server which is using real certificate from the React Native app it works well. The problem is only with localhost running IIS.

However when I call the API from React Native app it throws "Network request failed". I'm sure this has something to do with certificates. The local IIS has self signed certificate. If I understood correctly the same certificate has to be installed also on Android device. I have done that but still giving me the same error. Also tried to use mkcert to create a certificate and use that but no success.

I have googled a lot about this and found lots of discussions and tried different things I found. So far no success. I think I just need the correct, up-to-date info how to do this since many of the discussions are too old and not relevant anymore.

What kind of certificate I need? IIS self-signed or created by mkcert? If mkcert, how does the create command go when the machine needs to be accessible by IP?

What should be in network_security_config file that is used by AndroidManifest?

Comment: create the certificate with the local CA which can be trusted by your device. Use `mkcert [IP]` where [IP] is your machine's IP address in the LAN. import the certificate on iis. install the Ca certificate on your android device. add this code in network_security_config.xml file: `<network-security-config>  
  <base-config> <trust-anchors> <certificates src="system" /> <certificates src="user" /> </trust-anchors> </base-config></network-security-config>`. Reference this file in your `AndroidManifest.xml` under `application` tag: `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

Comment: Thanks, but mkcert [IP] creates two .pem files and IIS expects the file to be .pfx. What should I do?

Comment: you could use openssl tool to convert the certificate from pem to pfx. or use this PowerShell command `$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import("path\to\cert.pem")
$key = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("path\to\key.pem")
$cert.PrivateKey = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($cert)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("path\to\certificate.pfx", $cert.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, "your-password"))`